# Want to concatenate Value of one map to key of another map

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, hashtable

I want to concatenate to the value of one map to key of another map and add them into list.
Compare value on basis of key of first map to value of another map.
e.g:

```
map1= {37=core__error_code_based, 153=core__app_dialog, 123=core__date}


map2={copy_2=37,button_back=37,button_cancel=153,button_confirm=153}
```

My approach is in first loop  i get the key of map1 and then in second loop iterate the map2 values on basis map1 key.
So that I get the value of map1 and key of map2 and later concatenate in string.

```java
List<String> finalKey=new ArrayList<>();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String,String>> entrySet=map1.entrySet().iterator();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String,String>> pageKey=map2.entrySet().iterator();
        while(entrySet.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry<String,String> entry = entrySet.next();
            Map.Entry<String,String> pageValue = pageKey.next();

            while(entry.getKey()==pageValue.getValue()){
                finalKey.add(entry.getValue()+"__"+pageValue.getKey());
            }
        }
```

I had tried using iterator and entryset to iterate through the both map but not succeed

> {core__error_code_based__copy_2,core__error_code_based__button_back,core__app_dialog__button_confirm,core__app_dialog__button_cancel}

Comment: *"I had tried using iterator and entryset to iterate through the both map but not succeed"* Show us what you tried, otherwise how can we help you figure out what you did wrong? Right now, question appears to be an attempt to make us write your code for you. Show you attempt, and we'll help.

Comment: Hint: Iterate `map2`, lookup in `map1`

Comment: Hey @Andreas , I updated the code but it didn't work. IK can't iterate it with map2 , because map2 contain multiple values for same key, I had unique key in map1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i achieved this using

```
public class translatekeyName {
    static List<String> finalString = new ArrayList<>();

    public static Map<String, String> initialMap() {
        Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
        map1.put("37", "core__error_code_based");
        map1.put("153", "core__app_dialog");
        return map1;
    }

    public static Map<String, String> secondMap() {
        Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
        map2.put("copy_2", "37");
        map2.put("button_back", "37");
        map2.put("button_cancel", "153");
        map2.put("button_confirm", "153");
        return map2;
    }

    public List<String> concatenateString(Map page, Map source) {
        Map<String, String> moduleKey = page;
        Map<String, String> pageKey = source;
        List<String> temp;

        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> entrySet = page.entrySet().iterator();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> pageKeyset = source.entrySet().iterator();
        for (String value : moduleKey.keySet()) {
            temp = getallKeys(source, value);
            String tempValue = moduleKey.get(value);
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
                tempValue += "__" + temp.get(i);
                finalString.add(tempValue);
            }

        }

        return finalString;
    }

    static <K, V> List<K> getallKeys(Map<K, V> mapOfWords, V value) {
        List<K> keylist = null;


        if (mapOfWords.containsValue(value)) {

            keylist = new ArrayList<>();

            for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : mapOfWords.entrySet()) {

                if (entry.getValue().equals(value)) {
                    keylist.add(entry.getKey());
                }
            }
        }

        return keylist;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        translatekeyName obj = new translatekeyName();
        obj.concatenateString(initialMap(), secondMap());
        System.out.println(finalString);
    }

}
```